# Numlock don't stay on

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, numlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force numlock to be on on boot at login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/force-numlock-to-be-on-on-boot-at-login-screen)

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and the numlock doesn't work to me. I put it on but it go off automatically.
    I tried a new installation but the problem persist.

```
In 11.10 was working normally.

Both versions is x86_64 and the keyboard is USB.
```